# lookahead algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, search, tree

I have a network (a graph) of 50 vertices and 70 edges. I grow this network iteratively by adding an edge between the two vertices for which a new edge improves a given fitness metric the most. This works quite well looking ahead just one step, but I'd like to see if I get better results looking ahead n steps.

So... I am trying to implement a search algorithm in order to find the network's best combination of iterative changes by looking ahead n steps into the futures.

This algorithm should evaluate the fitness difference between the network at iteration t and the network at iteration t+n, pick the first step of the path that leads to the best fitness improvement, and once again look n steps ahead, repeat until I reach a good enough overall network fitness.

Alas, I'm having a lot of difficulties wrapping my head around this problem. I think I managed to hard-code an algorithm that looks ahead just two steps, but it's not looking good and is definitely not easily scalable to other steps I'd like to try. It's bad, but it should be enough to make my question clearer.

Here's my code, and my question:

```
from igraph import *

def comp_delta(ER,ER_old): # evaluates the graph

n_modu = ER.modularity(ER.community_multilevel(return_levels=False),weights=None)
o_modu = ER_old.modularity(ER_old.community_multilevel(return_levels=False),weights=None)

return float(n_modu - o_modu) / float(o_modu)


graph = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(30, .1, directed=False, loops=False) # create a random root graph of density 0.1
rootGraph = graph

score = []

# STEP 1
for n1 in range(30):
    for n2 in range(n1,30):
        if graph.are_connected(graph.vs[n1],graph.vs[n2]) == False and n1 != n2:
            graphOld = graph.as_undirected()
            graph.add_edge(rootGraph.vs[n1],rootGraph.vs[n2])
            graphStep1 = graph

            # STEP 2
            for d1_1 in range(30):
                for d1_2 in range(d1_1,30):
                    if graph.are_connected(graph.vs[d1_1],graph.vs[d1_2]) == False and d1_1 != d1_2:
                        graphOld.add_edge(rootGraph.vs[d1_1],rootGraph.vs[d1_2])
                        score.append([n1,n2,d1_1,d1_2,comp_delta(graphOld,rootGraph)])
                        graphOld = graphStep1.as_undirected()

            graph = graphStep1.as_undirected()

print score # array that can be sorted to retrieve both the best score and its path.
```

How to change this code so I can 1) look n steps into the future, and retrieve the path that led to the best improvement of the metric?

Please let me know if I'm not being clear, I'll update the message consequently. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having trouble wrapping your head around the problem, you need to break it into smaller steps.

Think about what you're trying to acheive:

> I am trying to implement a search algorithm in order to find the network's best combination of iterative changes by looking ahead n steps into the futures

And what your inputs to the system are:

- initial graph
- number of iterations `n` (lets say we choose 3)
- ranking function that determines fitness of a graph (or perhaps relative improvement over a previous graph)

So we need to write a function that takes these inputs and returns a new graph with the optimal edge added.

```
def add_optimal_edge(graph, rank, n=1): # you don't need to pass in the rank function necessarily
    ...
```

Now what does this function do? Well for each future generation it has to iterate over every possible new edge, create a new graph with this edge added and compare the new graph to the old one (basically what you're already doing).

But how does it determine which edge is optimal? Well for each new edge it has to look at the new graph and iterate over all possible new edges and create new graphs for those and then iterate over all possible new edges and new graphs for *those* .. etc .. .and then compare each final graph to the original - selecting the optimal first step, based on the ranking of the original graph to the final generation. *phew*

We want some code that does something like:

```
for generation in range(n):
    new_graphs = (graph.add_edge(e) for e in graph.possible_new_edges())
```

But subsequent generations will need to do this over a list of graphs (not a single one), so perhaps start out with a list and work from there:

```
graphs = [graph] # start off with just one graph
for generation in range(n):
    graphs = (graph.add_edge(e) for graph in graphs for e in graph.possible_new_edges())
```

This uses generator comprehensions so that memory usage doesn't balloon out of control, and it keeps overwriting `graphs` so that each subsequent generation is iterating over a larger set. Then compare each graph to the original and find the best:

```
best = max(graphs, key=lambda g: rank(graph, g)) # select best graph by ranking it against original
```

Okay, we've found the best, but we need to know what the first generation was that led us to get there. One way to do that would be to track the path of previous graphs as we go instead of just the latest graph, so the items we're iterating over are now lists of graphs (a path)

```
def add_optimal_edge(graph, rank, n=1):
    paths = [[graph]] # start off with just one graph path, which contains a single graph
    for generation in range(n):
        # path[-1] is the latest graph for each generation
        paths = (path + path[-1].add_edge(e) for path in paths for e in path[-1].possible_new_edges())
    # select best path by comparison of final generation against original graph
    best = max(paths, lambda path: rank(graph, path[-1])) 
    return best[1] # returns the first generation graph
```

The final result is concise, but the inner generator comprehension is a little long winded - you could probably refactor this out to a generator function to make it more readable. If you fill in the details for the extra functions I've added, you should be well on your way to a solution.

Comment: Wow, that looks like magic to me :) thank so much, this is some great learning (once I've got it understood completely) :D

I'm actually wondering: how does possible_new_edges() works?

Comment: @Rodolphe you have to write it - from your existing code it looks like you just iterate over all possible vertex combinations

Comment: oh of course... There's some stuff I don't quite get yet, so I'll ask another question (I don't want to pollute this one) :) I'll check it solved as soon as I understand enough... Thanks so much!