# Generator comprehensions for look ahead algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, generator, list-comprehension, igraph

I called for help yesterday on how to look ahead in Python. My problem was to iterate through all the possible edges to add to a network, and for each possible network with an edge added, look at all the possible edges to add, and so on (n depth). At the end, compare all networks produced at depth n with the root network, and actually add the best first step (best first edge to add to accomplish the best result at depth n). When that first edge is added, do the depth search again, and so on until a good network is found. Like a moving window, I may say (see [lookahead algorithm in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437322/lookahead-algorithm-in-python) for a more thorough explanation of the problem).

Unfortunately for the clarity of the question, the code requires igraph, which is available here: http://igraph.org/python/#downloads

@Peter Gibson promptly answered, guiding me through the logic of Generator comprehensions, and helped me produce this code:

```
from igraph import * # http://igraph.org/python/

def delta(g,gOld): # evaluates the improvement of the graph from one generation to the next 
   print "delta"
   return g.diameter()-gOld.diameter()

def possible_new_edges(G):
    print "Possible new edges"
    allPossibleNewEdges = []
    for n1 in range(50):
        for n2 in range(n1,50):
            if G.are_connected(G.vs[n1],G.vs[n2]) == False and n1 != n2:
                allPossibleNewEdges.append(G.vs[n1],G.vs[n2])
    return allPossibleNewEdges

def add_optimal_edge(graph, n=3):
    print "Add optimal edge"

    paths = [[graph]] # start off with just one graph path, which contains a single graph
    for generation in range(n):
        print "Generation:", generation

        # path[-1] is the latest graph for each generation
        paths = (path + path[-1].add_edge(e) for path in paths for e in path[-1].possible_new_edges())
    # select best path by comparison of final generation against original graph 
    best = max(paths, lambda path: comp_delta(path[-1],graph)) 
    return best[1] # returns the first generation graph

graph = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(50, .15, directed=False, loops=False) # create a random root graph of density 0.15

add_optimal_edge(graph)
```

The generator is concise and elegant. Let's say a little too elegant for my unwieldy Python style, and there are a few things I need to understand to make it work. The code runs with this error:

```
return best[1] # returns the first generation graph
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I think it's because of a wrong use of functions with the generator...

So, my question is: what's the proper way to use functions in such a generator? I need to call possible_new_edges() and delta(), what do I need to pass them (the graph?) and how to do so?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Oops, the question is being down voted because of the reference to another question? Or is it just plein unclear or useless? Please let me know, I'll then edit accordingly

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the code does nothing". What is the return value after you call `add_optimal_edge(graph)`? Do you get an exception? I can't run your code because it relies on some code you haven't shown (a library, presumably, though you haven't applied a tag for it or specified what it is in the question text), so there's no way for me to try it out myself. You need to explain *in depth* what is going on.

Comment: oh ok... thanks for the precisions. So the library called is igraph (http://igraph.org/python/), which help create and manipulate graphs. It's great.

The code runs fine, no exception raised, it just looks like it iterates over nothing. As if the functions weren't called at each iteration. This is why I'm guessing my function are not called properly.

It's the first time I put my hand in a generator, sorry for the lack of precision or precise vocabulary.

Cheers!

Comment: How can you tell the functions aren't being called? Have you added some debugging stuff you haven't mentioned? What does the `add_oprimal_edge` call at the end return?

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I was running a slightly different code on my computer. The code does raise an error after printing "Add optimal edge Generation: 0 Generation: 1 Generation: 2", please see the edited question.

Sorry for the waste of time @Blckknght

Comment: That error doesn't make much sense. The name `best` is assigned on the line immediately before the `return`. Are you *sure* the code you're showing is what you're running now? Rather than editing code in the question edit box, you may want to copy and paste what you have in your code editor.

Comment: You're right, the code was different... hum...

Here's a gist, with actual actual code, promise: https://gist.github.com/rodolpheg/c8cdda8d0c62a13e375b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying the code from [your gist](https://gist.github.com/rodolpheg/c8cdda8d0c62a13e375b), I found several fairly minor errors that were preventing the code from running. I've included fixed code below. However, this doesn't really solve the problem. That's because your algorithm needs to consider a truly vast number of potential graphs, which it cannot do in any sort of reasonable time.

In my testing, looking one step ahead works perfectly well, but looking two steps takes a very long time (10s of minutes, at least, I've never waited for it to finish) and three steps will probably take days. This is because your `possible_new_edges` function returns more than a thousand possible edges. Each one will be added to a copy of your initial graph. Then for each each succeeding step, the process will repeat on each of the expanded graphs from the previous step. This results in an exponential explosion of graphs, as you have to evaluate something on the order of `1000**n` graphs to see which is the best.

So, to get a practical result you'll still need to change things. I don't know graph theory or your problem domain well enough to suggest what.

Anyway, here are the changed parts of the "working" code (with the original comments removed so that my notes on what I've changed are more clear):

```
def possible_new_edges(G):

    print("Possible new edges")

    allPossibleNewEdges = []
    for n1 in range(50):
        for n2 in range(n1,50):
            if G.are_connected(G.vs[n1],G.vs[n2]) == False and n1 != n2:
                allPossibleNewEdges.append((G.vs[n1],G.vs[n2]))        # append a tuple
    return allPossibleNewEdges

def add_optimal_edge(graph, n=3):

    print("Add optimal edge")

    paths = [[graph]]
    for generation in range(n):

        print("Generation:", generation)

        paths = (path + [path[-1] + e]   # use + to add an edge, and to extend the path
                 for path in paths
                 for e in possible_new_edges(path[-1]))   # call this function properly
    best = max(paths, key=lambda path: comp_delta(path[-1],graph)) 
    return best[1]
```

If the generator expression in the loop confuses you, it might help to replace it with a list comprehension (by replacing the outermost parentheses with square brackets). You can then inspect the `paths` list inside the loop (and do things like print its `len()`). The logic of the code is the same either way, the generator expressions just put off computing the expanded results until the `max` function starts iterating over `paths` in order to find the best scoring one.

Using list comprehensions will work for `n=1` certainly, but you may start running out of memory as you try `n=2` (and you certainly will for `n=3` or more). The version above won't you run out of memory (as the generator expression only expands `O(n)` graphs at a time), but that doesn't mean it runs fast enough to inspect billions of graphs in sensible amount of time.

Comment: This looks really good, I can't thank you enough for all your efforts. I'll be able to check it in depth in a few days, I'll get back to comment then... Cheers!

Comment: A quick run, and it seems to work great... IT's so CPU intensive though... With a very small graph of 10 vertices, looking up to depth 3 or 4 seems feasible. I'm working with bigger graphs though, maybe I need to take a look at more cpu efficient methods (monte carlo?). Thank you so much once again!

Comment: @Rodolphe perhaps try running it in http://pypy.org/ - it tends to be much faster if you can get all of the dependencies running